# Is there a way to get the Current Date/Time from a Release Gate REST API Call

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Im trying to build a Release Gate using the REST API function, that checks a returned field value against the current date/time, but I cant figure out a way of getting the current date/time

Is there a simple way of achieving this ?

Ideally it would be great to be able to get the highlighted Timestamp
[image: Ideally it would be great to be able to get the highlighted Timestamp]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get the Current Date/Time from a Release Gate REST API Call

There is a specific variable for the **release pipeline** named "`Release.Deployment.StartTime`" or if you use it in powershell the environment variable is "`Release_Deployment_StartTime`":

```
$CurrentTime= $Env:Release_Deployment_StartTime
Write-Host "Current time is $CurrentTime"
```

It's in UTC and the format is "`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ`"
eg: "`2021-09-24 02:27:44Z`"

[image]

Comment: Wont Release_Deployment_StartTime give me the time that the Release kicked off ? Im actually looking for the time that each Gate Inspection kicks off